# Run Scalding Test Job in Hadoop with JobTest class

Tags: scala, hadoop, scalding

I'm not able to run scalding test with `JobTest` class. Below is the command. How to send command of that?

```
Hadoop jar com.scala-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.twitter.scalding.JobTest com.scala.etl --hdfs --input --output
```

facing below problem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.twitter.scalding.JobTest.main([Ljava.lang.String;)

Answer (score 1):

JobTest is not executed on Hadoop - they are executed in scalatest/JUnit. The way you run the test depends on how your project is built.

For example, take a look at this test file: https://github.com/danosipov/scalding-word-histogram-example/blob/master/src/test/scala/WordHistogramJobSpec.scala

That test is executed by running `sbt test` in the home directory, which runs the test locally on the development machine.